# CAnt verify custom Sub domain for gltlab pages

Tags: git, dns, gitlab, subdomain

I was trying to add a custom subdomain for my gitlab page. I have a domain that I bought from [www.bigrockin/](http://bigrock.in)  I added the CNAME and TXT in the DNS management area of my domain. But i couldn't verify the domain yet in gitlab. Every time i try to verify, Gitlab says unable to verify the domain. I cant find any mistake that i did. Anyone can help me to solve the problem.

Comment: It will be very helpful if you tell us the domain name and the records' hostnames, so we can check them. Also it will be good to know if your DNS is at `bigrock` or at a third-party?

Comment: thanks, @lanexbg  --   The subdomain is http://fab.suhailp.com   and my gitlab page address is http://suhailjr.gitlab.io/fabacademy/ . I was using my domain in Namecheap but the server is no longer available. So i changed the name server to bigrock back again.

Comment: thank you @Lanexbg. i figured out the problem, it was due to the DNS error. Now fixed